# Search efficiently for records matching given set of properties/attributes and their values (exact match, less than, greater than)

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, data-structures, complexity-theory

It is fairly simple problem to describe. However I could not come up with any reasonable solution so solution may or may not be so easy to cook up. Here is the problem:

Let there be many records describing some objects. For example:

```
{
  id         : 1,
  kind       : cat,
  weight     : 25 lb,
  color      : red
  age        : 10,
  fluffiness : 98 
  attitude   : grumpy
}

{
  id       : 2,
  kind     : robot,
  chassis  : aluminum,
  year     : 2015,
  hardware : intel curie,
  battery  : 5000,
  bat-life : 168,
  weight   : 0.5 lb,
}

{
  id       : 3,
  kind     : lightsaber,
  color    : red,
  type     : single blade,
  power    : 1000,
  weight   : 25 lb,
  creator  : Darth Vader
}
```

Attributes are not pre-specified so an object could be described using any attribute-value pairs.
If there are 1 000 000 records/objects there could easily be 100 000 different attributes.

**My goal is to efficiently search through the data structure/s that will contain all records and if possible to come up with answer (quickly) which records match the given conditions.**

For example a search query could be: `Find all cats that weigh more than 20 and are older than 9 and are more fluffy than 98 and are red and whose attitude is "grumpy".`

We can assume that there could be infinite number of records and infinite number of attributes but any search query contains no more than 20 numerical (lt,gt) clauses.

One possible implementation using SQL/MySQL I could think of was using fulltext indexes.

For example I could store non numeric attributes as "kind_cat color_red attitude_grumpy", search through them to narrow the resultset and then scan table containing numeric attributes for matches. It seems however (I am not sure at this point) that gt, lt searches might be costly in general using this strategy (I would have to do at least N joins for N numerical clauses).

I thought of MongoDB thinking of the problem, but although MongoDB naturally allows me to store key-value pairs, searching by some fields (not all) means that I must create indexes that contain all keys in all possible orders/permutations (and this is impossible).

Can this be done efficiently (maybe in logarithmic time??) using MySQL or any other dbms? - If not, is there data structure (maybe some muti-dimensional tree?) and algorithm that allows efficiently executing this kind of searches on a large scale (considering both time and space complexity)?

If it isn't possible to solve the problem defined this way are there any heuristic approaches that solve it without sacrificing too much.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right your thinking something like:

```
create table t 
( id int not null
, kind varchar(...) not null
, key varchar(...) not null
, val varchar(...) not null
, primary key (id, kind, key) );
```

There are several problems with this approach, you can google for EAV to find out more. One example is that you will have to cast val to the appropriate type when doing comparisons ( '2' > '10' )

That said, an index like:

```
create unique index ix1 on t (kind, key, val, id)
```

will reduce the pain you will be suffering slightly, but the design wont scale well and with 1E6 of rows and 1E5 attributes the performance will be far from good. Your example query would look something like:

```
select a.id
from ( select id 
       from ( select id, val 
              from t 
              where kind = 'cat'
                and key = 'weight' 
            )
       where cast(val as int) > 20
     ) as a
join ( select id 
       from ( select id, val 
              from t 
              where kind = 'cat'
                and key = 'age' 
            )
       where cast(val as int) > 9
     ) as b
     on a.id = b.id
join ( ...
                and key = 'fluffy' 
            )
       where cast(val as int) > 98
     ) as c
     on a.id = c.id
join ...
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't scale well and your sql snippet illustrates exactly what I thought of. In fact I do not expect specific example / proof of concept as answer but general solution that scales ( the concept itself ).
Thank you for your time and answering, though.